# Force Angular 7 website to load resources from server

Tags: angular

When ever I deploy a new version of my Angular website to the server and view it on my browser, I still see an older version of my application on the browser and I have to clear the browser cache to view the new version of the website. Is there a way I can force the website to load resources of the application from the server rather than displaying it from the cache. Thank you . I added the below tags in index.html. But it is not helping

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
 <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
 <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Comment: what kind of server are you using ?

Comment: I am using ECS server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this header to your server:

```
"Cache-Control", "public, max-age=0"
```

for NodeJS (express) use this middleware

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=0");
   return next();
});
```

Comment: For ECS Server im not sure how to do it however you need to add this header somewhere in your server configuration ;)